# How to empty ALL the cache via CLI on TYPO3 v.6 during Extbase development?

Tags: caching, typo3

During extension developement for TYPO3 v.6 some times it's some boring to clean the cache again and again : in backend, in typo3temp.

Is there a CLI helper for that to erase ALL the cache via shell ?

Answer (score 1):

this question is a bit old but I think someone else would be useful.

I have developed an little extension which eliminates typo cache through the command line.
You need to create a user backend "no admin" to complete the process, otherwise it will not work.

STEPS:

1. INSTALL the extension http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/clear_t3cache
2. CREATE a user backend with the following name: "_cli_lowlevel" with a random password, without any additional privileges.
3. Now, in the root typo3 directory, EXECUTE: php typo3/cli_dispatch.phpsh clear_t3cache

That's it

Answer (score 0):

There is something better, an extension called `uncache` :)

See here: http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/uncache

Just don't forget to disable it again when going live.

Comment: Great, I need to test the performance of TYPO3 v6 with *uncache*. Thanks again to @NamelessCoder. I need to check the extension, if it possible to make a CLI interface.